# Why php PDO uses a different from hostname to the one used by mysql_connect() when connecting to a remotely hosted mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, hostname

I've mysql database and php/apache on two different servers: let's say hostphp.domain.com and hostmysql.domain.com.

On the mysql server I've set a user "my_user" with permissions to connect to "my_database" db from the specific host "hostphp.domain.com".

When I connect to it using mysql_connect it does right. But when I do it via php PDO I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'my_user'@'%' to database 'my_database'
```

I've done some tests and I found the problem is ...@'%', mysql is refusing that connection because "my_user" does not have permission to connect from any host.

Also I've tried to connect using mysql_connect with a wrong password to see the error and I get this:

```
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'my_user'@'hostphp.domain.com' (using password: YES).
```

The difference is in ..@'%' and ...@'hostphp.domain.com'.

So that's my question, why php pdo do not declare hostname when connecting to a remote host? (or is doing that wrong).

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Edit.
Some code example, this does not work:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=hostmysql.domain.com;port=3306;dbname=my_database',
        'my_user',
        'my_pass'
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

but this works ok:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('hostmysql.domain.com', 'my_user', 'my_pass');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: could you show some code please? post the working code and the non-working code as well.

Comment: Please do `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'my_user'@'hostphp.domain.com'`?  You probably need to [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant.html) `my_user` access to `my_database`.

Comment: @eggyal, yes, I've already done, note that when I connect using mysql_connect It get connected right. I've connected using a wrong pass only to the error, and you can see that in that case the hostname is correctly setted.

Comment: Just because the user can *connect* doesn't mean that it has permission to *do* anything.

Comment: @t.heintz I've added some code examples.

Comment: Exactly, per @eggyal 's suggestion - verify that when connected via `mysql_connect()` that you can actually call `mysql_select_db()` and execute a query successfully.

Comment: @eggyal, right! I understand what you mean, thanks, I will check it, I think the problem could be there.

Comment: The error you are showing `Access denied for user 'my_user'@'%' to database 'my_database'` means the connection to the server was successful but trying to select that database was not.  So you are connecting.  In your mysql example, you connect but never try to select a database.  PDO connects and tries to select the DB as part of the connection.

Comment: Thank you so much, guys! as @eggyal has suggested, the problem was that the user has permissions only to connect but nothing else. I feel a little stupid for this, but I've no control on database server and I've trusted on the guy that manages it.

Comment: @drew010, exactly, that was my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have successfully connected to the host using mysql_connect, but you got no errors because you did not attempt to select the database.

Your user probably doesn't have access to your database.

Try running mysql_select_db("my_database"); after connected to the host and you should get the same error.